# How not to repeat text in linesimbolizer?

Tags: geoserver, sld

I need make a sld style with line and label above. But it's not that simple because I have some additional requirements:

1. Label without repeat
2. Label fitted in line in ideal or put in line center.
3. Label gonna be multiple lines

For repeat i found [that](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-reference/labeling.html#labeling-repeat):

```
Normally GeoServer labels each line only once, regardless of length.
```

IS it mean that i get only one label for each line?

For multiline:

```
<VendorOption name="autoWrap">50</VendorOption>
```

But how can i fit label? For fiting im understand autoselect fontsize and stretching label by line lenght.
Its possible? Where i can find any examples?

Comment: can you post examples that you have tried and that don't meet your requirements